# how to get nearest greater integer value in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios

I have some math related code in my iPhone app. i have some equation as bellow.

```
int tempVal = 56/50;
NSLog(@"%d", tempVal);
```

Output
   `2013-03-25 16:29:36.749 TestApp[1467:c07] 1`

Actually `56/50 = 1.12` and my `tempVal` is integer that's why my result is 1.

But i want nearer greater value then result. i mean i want `2` as my output. i can't make increment programmatically in `tempVal` like
`tempVal+1` or `tempVal = tempVal + 1` or something.

Is there any possibility to do it ??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the way to do it (assuming you want `tempVal` to remain int rather than float):

```
int tempVal = ceil((float)56/50);

NSLog(@"%d", tempVal);
```

Answer (score 2):

The same rules as `C` apply: 56 and 50 are ints, so 56/50 is an `integer` divide. `Integer` division truncates so 56/50 produces the integer 1.if you are taking `float` values then it works fine.

```
float tempVal = 56.0/50.0;
    NSLog(@"%f", ceil(tempVal));
```

or

```
float tempVal =(float) 56/50;
    NSLog(@"%f", ceil(tempVal));
```

Comment: it is working fine if i use `56.0/50.0`. but not give result if u use `56/50`.

Answer (score 1):

you can simply use `%` modulus operator to check if their is a fraction in the answer and increment based on that check.

```
int tempVal = 56/50;
if ((56 % 50) > 0){
     tempVal ++;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
int firstValue = ...;
int secondValue = ...;

int result = (firstValue + (secondValue - 1)) / (secondValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

`int tempVal = (56 + (50 - 1)) / 50;`

More generically (for positive values):  `int result = (value + (divisor - 1)) / divisor;`

Very basic up-rounding.  Should be in every programmer's toolbox.

Answer (score -1):

Just use `ceil()`:

```
int tempVal =  ceil((float)56/50);
```

Comment: This won't work because 56/50 already returns an `int` result, so this is equivalent to `ceil(1)`.
That's why `ceil((float)56/50)` is necessary (my answer).